# manipulating lists and arrays in a certain order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of form:

```
['a b 1 2', 'c d 3 4']
```

I'm ultimately trying to end up with a 4 vertical numpy arrays.  E.g., `['a','c']` and `[1,2]`

I'm getting a little confused using the various split functions, array splits, etc..

Super noob question and this is more an exercise in doing this efficiently as possible.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Numpy arrays do not handle multiple data types in the same array, unless you are using a record array. It is also unclear what you mean by ending up with a '4 vertical numpy arrays'. Could you add more detail to your question?

Comment: Is there any logic behind the desired result?

Comment: Thanks Josh.  I'm looking to translate the list above (which is organized as rows) ['Apple Blue 1 6.5','Banana Red 4 7.733']  into numpy arrays with members that would have the same types ['Apple', 'Banana'] and ['Blue','Red'] and [1,4]

Comment: in your examples did you mean [1,3]?

Answer (score 1):

There is no functionality in numpy to split the strings in a python list of strings into separate arrays directly. If these strings are from reading in a text file with consistent column data types, consider using `numpy.genfromtxt`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

**Edit** or you can coerce you array into a format that `np.genfromtxt` can read as **jterrace** notes in his response.

Answer (score 1):

You can read it in as a record array:

```
>>> A = ['a b 1 2', 'c d 3 4']
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> import numpy
>>> s = StringIO('\n'.join(A))
>>> data = numpy.genfromtxt(s, dtype=[('letter1', 'S1'), ('letter2', 'S1'), ('num1', 'f8'), ('num2', 'f8')])
```

Then to access the columns:

```
>>> data['letter1']
array(['a', 'c'], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>> data['num1']
array([ 1.,  3.])
```

Note that this is limited to fixed-size strings. Not sure whether this is an issue for your data.

Comment: +1 for adding the intermediate step to go from my suggestion to something functional

Answer (score 0):

```
  A = ['a b 1 2', 'c d 3 4']
  filter(lambda x:x[0].strip() or x[1].strip(),zip (*A))
  #[('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '4')]
```

not numpy arrays though

[edit] assuming I understood the goal which Im not sure I did...